# How to solve this error : TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python

```
>>> g = input ("enter:")
enter: 50 
>>> g + 100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    g + 100
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`input ("enter:")` returns string and you cannot add string and int as your error tells you

You must convert it to int type before

```
int(g) + 100
```

Comment: why is that converting int type? please explain me, i'm not an expert, trying some simple codes for my exam

Comment: [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) is a constructor to `int` type, so as a result you will get number value

Comment: so this int is the correct one or is there a any other way?

Comment: This is a plenty of other ways, but this is the easiest